# HTMLInstance.attachEvent onload

Tags: javascript

The following code works with IE9 but not with IE8

```
     HTMLInstance.attachEvent("onclick" , function() { } ); // work with IE8
     HTMLInstance.attachEvent("onload" , function() { } ); // does not work with IE8 but works with IE9
```

How can I fix the problem with onlaod event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no onload event in IE 8 so you should use `window.onload` or `window.body.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){

}
```